# How to getSelectedRows on ngClick in agGrid-angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid-angular

Calling `gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()` on ngClick it returns `[]`, but calling it in `gridOptions.onRowClicked` it returns the selected rowData correctly. Why `api.getSelectedRows()` returns empty on ngClick? How to get the selected rows on ngClick?

I'm trying to use agGrid in my angularJs project. I need to get the selected row(s) as input to a form to edit/update, when the editing-button appending to a specific row is clicked.

Here is the code I used to invoke `updateRecord` which then tries to `getSelectedRows` (but failed).

```
gridOptions.rowData = genRows(opa.fieldParams, opa.values, function (row) {
  row.verticalTailer = `<i class="far fa-edit" style="cursor: pointer;"
  ng-click="$root.$broadcast('table:updateRecord', {name: '${opa.name}'})">
  </i>`;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use ag-grid api and use it. They have given a built-in function to get selected rows from the grid.

To achieve that, first, you have to register the ag-grid's api in your scope.

```
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    };
```

And then you can use your $scope.gridApi on ngClick as given below, where getSelectedRows() will called on ngClick.

```
$scope.getSelectedRows= function(){
    $scope.selectedRows= $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I never know/try registering `gridApi` before. I tried `api.selection` and not successful so far. agGrid document says `api.getSelectedRows()` instead of `api.selection.getSelectedRows()`. Will try more.

Comment: @zipper Maybe the ag grid api differs for its different version, I'm sure, you can take it forward from here :)

Comment: I googled the keyword `onRegisterApi` and got links to `ui-grid` instead of `ag-grid`...

Answer (score 0):

I dived into the ag-grid angularjs sample conde in the ag-grid document and found that I can simply use `data` (silently added by ag-grid to the scope) to refer to the current row in the template, so I can simply change `ng-click="$root.$broadcast('table:updateRecord', {name: '${opa.name}'}` to `ng-click="$root.$broadcast('table:updateRecord', {name: '${opa.name}', data: data}` in my template code, no need to getSelectedRows() in the controller.